# PHP act on sub-array if first array = x

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (in PHP) that looks similar to:

```
$array_name [0] [0] ['value0']
                [1] ['value1']
                [2] ['value2']
            [1] [0] ['value0']
                [1] ['value1']
                [2] ['value2']
```

(this basically relates to $array_name['group']['subGroup']['value']

what I need is a way of telling it:

> if $array_name[0] (group 1) then do something,
>
> if $array_name[1] (group 2) do something else

but i can't see how I would do this (I'm sure the answer is right under my nose).

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by `if $array_name[0] (group 1) `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach ( $array_name as $group_key => $group) {
  switch ($group_key) {
    case 0:
      // do something for group0
    break;
    case 1:
      // do something for group1
    break;
  }
}
```